# How to style the actual header parts, and not just the content, of an expander

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF items control where I want to group items using an expander.

I have the following markup...

```
        <Window x:Class="ItemsControlGrouped.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ItemsControlGrouped"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
      <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate>
                <Expander IsExpanded="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                  <Expander.Header>
                    
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightGray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  />
                      <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding ItemCount}" />
                      <TextBlock Text=" item(s)"  />
                    </StackPanel>
                    
                  </Expander.Header>
                  <ItemsPresenter />
                  </Expander>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </Window.Resources>
      <ItemsControl Name="list">
        <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
          <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
        </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Border Margin="5" Padding="0" BorderThickness="1"  Background="LightBlue" CornerRadius="4">
              <TextBlock Padding="5" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Border>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapPanel>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      </ItemsControl>
    </Window>
```

I wish to style the expander panel, for example I would like the whole expander row to have a background colour, and maybe some padding etc.

Looking in the Visual Explorer, this all seems to be in an area `HeaderSite`, as we can see below...

[image]

So, the area in the red highlight, I would like to add a background too (not just the text box as can I have done in the template).

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.  To style that part of the Expander, you need to get pretty deep into the ControlTemplate.  Shown below is a basic example similar to a custom style of the ToggleButton and Expander that I've been using for several years.

```
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderToggleButton"
             TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding"
                    Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
                    Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Grid Height="24" Width="24">
                            <Border x:Name="border"
                                            CornerRadius="12"
                                            Background="Black"/>
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Fill="White"
                                        Data="M4.5 9 l4 0 l3.5 4.6667 l3.5 -4.6667 l4 0 l-7.5 10 z"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                             Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border"
                                                Property="Background"
                                                Value="DarkGray"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="arrow"
                                                Property="Fill"
                                                Value="LightGray"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                                             Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border"
                                                Property="Background"
                                                Value="White"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="arrow"
                                                Property="Fill"
                                                Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="arrow"
                                                Property="Data"
                                                Value="M4.5 15 l4 0 l3.5 -4.6667 l3.5 4.6667 l4 0 l-7.5 -10 z"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="ContentRow" Height="0" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    CornerRadius="2,2,0,0"
                                    Background="White">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                                                Style="{StaticResource ExpanderToggleButton}"
                                                IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">

                                </ToggleButton>
                                <!--This is the border that puts the styling around the Expander Header-->
                                <!--Add more detail here for a fancier header.-->
                                <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="DarkRed">
                                    <ContentPresenter Margin="4" 
                                            ContentSource="Header"
                                            TextBlock.Foreground="White"
                                            RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                                </Border>

                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="Content"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    CornerRadius="0,0,2,2">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="4" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded"
                                     Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentRow"
                                        Property="Height"
                                        Value="{Binding DesiredSize, ElementName=Content}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

[image]

The style I use has the toggle button almost as a separate entity from the 'header' text and background, but it's pretty easy to extend the background of the header underneath the toggle button if you're going for that look too.  Once you're this deep into the ControlTemplate, you pretty much have full control over how everything looks.

Comment: @Stebob Thanks for that. So look like need to replace the whole control template, which, if that's what we need to do, then that's what we need to do. Cheers